# Trying to find sets that satisfy a property

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I want to find examples of sets $A,B \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $A \cap B \neq \varnothing $ and $\sup( A \cap B ) < \sup A $, $\sup (A \cap B) < \sup B $

I have been trying to find an example, but I fail. I was thinking on exhibiting intervals, but they fail. But if I take $A = \{1,2 \} $ and $B = \{0,1,3 \} $ then $A \cap B = \{ 1 \} $ and $\sup A = 2 > \sup ( A \cap B ) = 1 $ and $\sup B = 3 > 1 $ as well. Is this correct?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absolutely correct.

You can make an even smaller example with $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1,3\}$.

An even smaller example is $A=\{1\}, B=\{1,3\}$, because as you wrote, you only want $\sup(A\cap B)\leq \sup A$, so this example, in which $\sup(A\cap B) = \sup(A)$ and $\sup(A\cap B) <\sup B$, still fits the demands.

This is also the smallest possible example (in terms of the size of $A$ and $B$), since if $|A|=|B|=1$, $A\cap B\neq \emptyset$ is only possible if $A=B$, in which case $\sup(A\cap B)=\sup(B)$ which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's right.

A bigger example might be:

$A = (1,7)$
$B = (5,10)$

So $A \cap B = (5,7)$.

Then $\sup(A) = 7 = \sup (A \cap B)$. This satisfies $\sup(A \cap B) \leq \sup A)$.
And $\sup(B) = 10$. Since $\sup (A \cap B) =7$, we clearly have that $\sup(A \cap B) < \sup(B)$.